# Handling Error While Compiling Using CodeDom

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, compiler-errors, codedom

So after fixing my problem while compiling code using CodeDom, I've encountered another problem relating to the code. This is confusing because the code works perfectly fine when I run it - it only happens when I try to compile it.
My code does this:
For every file in the directory C:\temp\ - if the file name contains "123" it adds it to a list of strings.

```
Dim file_list As New List(Of String)
        Dim temp_directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\temp\")
        Dim get_file_info As IO.FileInfo() = temp_directory.GetFiles()
        Dim item As IO.FileInfo
        For Each item In get_ssfn_files
            If item.ToString.Contains("123") Then
                file_list.Add(item.ToString)
            End If
        Next
```

Then, it will do something with each file in a for each statement.

```
For Each file_found in file_list
    'Do Something
Next
```

The error seems to happen on this line:

> For Each file_found in file_list

I dont know why, because like I said, the code works fine when I'm not compiling it with CodeDom. Anyone know how to go about fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is being compiled with `Option Infer Off`, you need to specify a type for `file_found`.

```
For Each file_found As String In file_list
    'Do Something
Next
```